# How to scale object dynamically up to canvas size in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I want to increase height and width of my svg image same as canvas height and width so that it look like background image of canvas. When I press Set Background button, one svg image will be set to canvas from my directory. I want to scale this image up to canvas height and width dynamically.

Expected Output: [I want this](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/test/after.PNG)

### Html

```
<h1>canvas</h1>
<canvas style="left: -300px; border: 1px dotted;" height="385" width="400" id="c"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="svg3" value="set background" />
```

### Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var colorSet="red";
    $("#svg3").click(function(){
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cd/-Islandshreyfingin.svg', function (objects, options) { 
            var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            shape.set({
                left: 150,
                top:200,
                //height: 700,
                //width: 700,
                scaleX: .35,
                scaleY:.35
            });

            if (shape.isSameColor && shape.isSameColor() || !shape.paths) {
                shape.setFill(colorSet);
            } else if (shape.paths) {
                for (var i = 0; i < shape.paths.length; i++) {
                    shape.paths[i].setFill(colorSet);
                }
            }

            canvas.add(shape);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my [FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjZa/4/).

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Your "I want this" link is dead (404).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You know your canvas width and height. So [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjZa/6/) will work:

```
shape.set({
    top: canvas.height/2,
    left: canvas.width/2,
    scaleY: canvas.height / shape.height,
    scaleX: canvas.width / shape.width
});
```

Comment: nice its work for me .how could i set this svg image to my canvas background, do you have any idea for it ?

Comment: Why not set `selectable: false` on that shape?

Comment: if i set selectable: false then how can i select it next time when i wish to change its fill color [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjZa/7/)

Comment: is there any method to change svg fill color without using active object function 'var canvas.getActiveObject();'

Comment: That has nothing to do with fill color. As long as you have a reference to `shape` you can change it. What `selectable: false` does is it removes the move/scale/rotate controls so that users can't change it.

Comment: So yes, as long as you can `shape.paths[i].setFill(colorSet);` why would you care about `getActiveObject`?

Comment: how to use shape.paths[i].setFill(colorSet); can you provide me demo with  update my fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/hxjZa/7/

Comment: you are great boss ! i really appreciate your work it solve my all problem.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the solution:

### HTML

```
<h1>canvas</h1>
<canvas style="left: -300px; border: 1px dotted;" height="585" width="400" id="c"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="svg3" value="set background" />
<input type="button" id="color" value="Change Image Color" />
```

### JavaScript

```
function setBackgroundColor(color) {
    if (background.isSameColor && background.isSameColor() || !background.paths) {
        background.setFill(color);
    } else if (background.paths) {
        for (var i = 0; i < background.paths.length; i++) {
            background.paths[i].setFill(color);
        }
    }
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var background;


$("#svg3").click(function() {
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cd/-Islandshreyfingin.svg', 
        function (objects, options) { 
            background = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);


            background.set({
                left: canvas.width/2,
                top: canvas.height/2,
                scaleY: canvas.height / background.width,
                scaleX: canvas.width / background.width,
                 selectable: false
            });

            setBackgroundColor('red');

            canvas.add(background);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
});

$("#color").click(function(){
    setBackgroundColor('blue');
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

working Demo [Fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxjZa/15/)